# Discord.js returning previous outputs

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot (in javascript), and when I run a command it runs a previous version of the code along with the new version. If this doesn't make sense, I have an image:
[(here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNuD3.png). In the blue border, are previous versions of code. The red border is the new code versions. I have tried looking to see if I am running the program twice (running `ps` in terminal) and there is only one `node main.js` program running. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have multiple terminals open/instances running?

Comment: no, in fact, I have terminal quit right now, and it gives just the blue border output. This version of the code is pretty old science I changed the output to flavor text a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

The ps command does not show all the processes. I needed to run `ps aux` to find the extra processes.